# Aura Component: Date/Time popup covered by date history

Tags: lightning-aura-components

please see the image below. Our users have been running into this issue where the user's past history is overlapping the out of the box (aura component - lightning:input) popup date selector. Has anyone else experienced a similar issue? Is there anyway to get around this using css or another method?

[image]

```
<lightning:input type="datetime" name="startdate" label="Start Date/Time" value="{!v.userrec.OOO_Start_Date_Time__c}"/>
```

Comment: This sounds like a Browser problem, not a Salesforce problem.

Comment: Thats what I thought initially as well. But I was able to fix it by adding autocomplete="off" to the lightning:input tag.

Comment: You should add it as an answer to this post. It's probably going to happen to others.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a solution to this problem. I added the attribute autocomplete="off" to the lightning:input tag.

```
<lightning:input type="datetime" name="startdate" label="Start Date/Time" value="{!v.userrec.OOO_Start_Date_Time__c}" autocomplete="off" />
```